Why does casting the value to a string change the behavior of the code in rewriting array values?
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to update values within an array. Specifically, this portion of my code seems problematic:
$response["rates"][$key[$i]] = (string) round($response["rates"][$key[$i]], 2);

Here's a var_dump of the array
array(11) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["provider"]=>
  string(32) "https://www.exchangerate-api.com"
  ["documentation"]=>
  string(42) "https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/free"
  ["terms_of_use"]=>
  string(38) "https://www.exchangerate-api.com/terms"
  ["time_last_update_unix"]=>
  int(1714003352)
  ["time_last_update_utc"]=>
  string(31) "Thu, 25 Apr 2024 00:02:32 +0000"
  ["time_next_update_unix"]=>
  int(1714090382)
  ["time_next_update_utc"]=>
  string(31) "Fri, 26 Apr 2024 00:13:02 +0000"
  ["time_eol_unix"]=>
  int(0)
  ["base_code"]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  ["rates"]=>
  array(162) {
    ["USD"]=>
    float(1)
    ["AED"]=>
    float(3.6699999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875)
    ["AFN"]=>
    float(72.1299999999999954525264911353588104248046875)
    ["ALL"]=>
    float(94.2999999999999971578290569595992565155029296875)
    ["AMD"]=>
    float(391.30000000000001136868377216160297393798828125)
    ["ANG"]=>
    float(1.79000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625)
    ["AOA"]=>
    float(843.5700000000000500222085975110530853271484375)
    ["ARS"]=>
    float(864.75)
  }
}

However, when I use the following line instead:
$response["rates"][$key[$i]] = round($response["rates"][$key[$i]], 2);

The values remain unchanged. I'm puzzled as to why casting to a string makes a difference in this context.
The rest of my code operates as intended. It fetches JSON data from a URL and converts it into an array.
Here's the code with comments:
<?php

$req_url = 'https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD'; // URL for the request
$response_json = file_get_contents($req_url); // Get JSON data from the URL as a string

$response = json_decode($response_json, true); // Convert the string to an array

$key = array_keys($response["rates"]); // Get all keys from the array
/* var_dump of $key
{
  [0]=>
  string(3) "USD"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "AED"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "AFN" and etc.
}
*/

if ('success' === $response["result"]) { // Check if the request was successful

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($response["rates"]); $i++) {
        // Attempt to update values in the array (doesn't seem to work as expected)
        // Do not change any value of array

        $response["rates"][$key[$i]] = round($response["rates"][$key[$i]], 2);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($response["rates"]); $i++) {
        // Another attempt to update values, casting to string this time
        // Change value of array after cast to string

        $response["rates"][$key[$i]] = (string)round($response["rates"][$key[$i]], 2);
    }

}

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried researching this issue but haven't found any solutions or explanations for this behavior.
(Arrays properties. Similar question on public forums, ChatGPT)

Most decimal fractions can't be represented exactly in floating point. var_dump() shows as much precision as it can, but casting to string will use the shortest value that has the same representation.

Are you sure? When I try it with PHP 8.2, the values are truncated.

@Barmar
This is the reason why I try to reduce them to 2 decimal places with the round() command. But the issue here, if I don't cast it to (string)  it do not change any values in array

@aynber
I also have php version 8.2. And i still have this issue.

I tried this but I can't really reproduce it. It would be helpful if you provide some sandbox which reproduces the issue. You can also try playing a bit with precision and serialize_precision ini settings. Might also be worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

https://3v4l.org/R1ceA shows your code with the json you get from the endpoint, all the numbers look to be limited to 2 decimals.

When I do $i = 3.6699999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875; var_dump($i); it prints float(3.67).

I get the same result in php 5.6 and 7.4 as well.

@Barmar
I check on my windows env everything work fine, but on my Linux(Ubuntu22.04) env it displays wrong. Maybe ii's problem with XAMPP. What should I do next?

I suspect there's a php.ini setting involved, but I don't know what to look for.

Check the precision setting in php.ini. It defaults to 14, when I change to 50 I get your result.

@Barmar
Now everything work as it should. Thank you.

I would like to thank everyone who tried to help resolve this issue.

After checking various compilation variants of https://3v4l.org/ and making sure that this is not a problem in the array or record, I found the issue.
The problem was in the php.ini file, namely in the value of precision.
Solution:
Check the precision setting in php.ini. It defaults to 14. When I change it to 50 we get the desired result.

Isn't that the opposite of the solution? I get the desired result using the default value, I reproduce your problem when I increase it to 50.
